# Saving settings based on strings

Tags: c#, settings

I need to save to a different setting based on the input string. Why will this line not work?

```
Properties.Settings.Default + colorOptionNametoSave = selectedIndexString;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Where the `colorOptionNametoSave` is a different color setting and the `selectedIndexString` is the value to save. However I get the message:

> Error 2: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer.

The only work around I can think of is a `switch` statement, but I have a lot of colors so that would be really long. Any ideas on a more efficient solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if`/`else` or a `switch` is what you are looking for.

You **cannot concatenate** a variable name!

So a solution for you would be something like this ( if `colorOptionNametoSave` is a string ):

```
if(colorOptionNametoSave == "Blue")
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Blue = selectedIndexString;
}
else if(colorOptionNametoSave == "Red")
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Red = selectedIndexString;
}
```

Comment: arg ok i was just hoping for a more elegant method. will start writing the 300+ case switch block then....haha.